# A One To Many relationship model where the data on the right side can be quite variable?

Tags: sql, orm, relational-database

Here is the problem I'm trying to solve:

```
Entity A : a_id
Entity B : b_id
One A can use Many B's. However, not all Bs are used by all As.
```

Here is the best example I can think of :

```
One teacher has many students.
Some students are taught by more than one teacher.
```

What is a relationship so I can add/remove students being taught by one teacher, but not affect the teachers already teaching said students?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a third table known as mapping between this two tables.create this table so:

```
Table Student_Teacher_Mapping

   Id (Int)
   TeacherId(Int)  // foreign key for teacher table  
   StudentId(Int)  // foreign key for student table
```

i think this is what you want.

Comment: So then it would be possible to have a OneToMany relationship on a Teacher<->Mapping?

Comment: yes.both student and teacher will have one to many relation with mapping table.for example teacher.mapping will contain all the students taught by that teacher.

Comment: Apparently my implementation of this method in Doctrine causes circulation and memory exhaustion. Guess I can't use ORM for this process.

Answer (score 2):

You need a StudentTeacher entity that will relate the two together.  It would have an a_id column and a b_id column.